# How to specify receiving device and port for an Android device shell connection?

Tags: android

I would like to use HEX values to

- Turn on display
- Turn off display
- volume on/off (ect..)

Currently the set up is one android device has another android display connected to its usb port. Using serial usb connection to connect to the serial port on android display.
I want to send on / off / volume hex code to that tty port/ COM port and have the display respond.

I know you can send like this:

```
AStream.Write(Array As Byte(0x01, 0x25, 0xF8, 0x45, 0x30, 0x05, 0x30, 0x31, 0x39, 0x37, 0x03 ))
```

But how do I specify the receiving device and its port?

Comment: Waht is an android display? Where did you buy it?

Comment: @blackapps it's basically a giant android tablet. Touch screen android, and allows RS232 control codes to be sent through a serial USB connection. My question is, is there a way to send these commands from one android device via ADB SHELL to the other android device ?